# Hibernate criteria query with collection of basic values

Tags: java, database, hibernate, criteria

I am newbie in Hibernate especially in Criteria API and I can't find answer on my question..
Here is simplified domain class:

```
@Entity
public class HDNewsPost implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    //other fields
    //..    

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "SD_SOLUTION.PBITSM_HD_NEWS_RECIPIENT_CODES",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "POST_ID"))
    @Column(name="POSITION_CODE")
    private List<String> recipientCodes;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I need restriction for criteria that will satisfy if some value (String code) is present in recipientCodes collection.

Comment: I have read this doc https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html And I don't saw useful restriction there

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html Please read documentation instead of api

Comment: I know how to use simple Criteria queries. I have read this link (your link) some months ago. Also in case if instead of basic object (String) were some model (Employee for example) then I know how to create query which will apply restriction on some Employee field for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my task! Here is full criteria query with part where I have a problem:

```
final Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(HDNewsPost.class);
criteria.setFirstResult(startFrom);
criteria.setMaxResults(maxResults);
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("publicationDate"));

if (code != null) {
    criteria.createAlias("recipientCodes", "rc", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.isEmpty("recipientCodes"),
        Restrictions.eq("rc.elements", code)));
}

return criteria.list();
```

I have found answer here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html#querycriteria-collections

"For queryng a collection of basic values, we still create the Criteria object against the collection, but to reference the value, **we use the special property "elements"**. For an indexed collection, we can also reference the index property using the special property "indices"."

Also, when creating alias your need to specify sql LEFT_JOIN (the default is INNER_JOIN)   or you will not get expected result, probably.